# Is there a free prompt?

Tags: websharper

I am learning `JavaScript` (via *Eloquent JavaScript*) and thought I would learn `Websharper` at the same time.

Is there access to `JavaScript`'s `prompt` command outside of `ExtJS`?

I searched online and couldn't find anything in the documentation that didn't require a license.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp is the browser built in JavaScript prompt() command. It is not as fancy as Ext.Msg.prompt() but is comparable.

Comment: @VanceCagle So How do I access the `prompt` command in `Websharper`? I thought it would be `Javascript.Prompt` but I didn't see it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have looked into what Websharper is before answering. When using JavaScript in the raw, you simply call prompt("What is your name?") by itself. Now, built in JavaScript commands do not behave exactly the same on every browser and this is why frameworks like ExtJS exist; they abstract the differences in JavaScript implementation on different browsers. It is possible that since Websharper is meant to be cross-browser, it doesn't want you calling such native methods. jQuery UI Dialog object may be the next best thing to ExtJS prompts http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed missing in the WebSharper API. I filed a [bug report](https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper/issue/206/no-binding-for-js-builtin-prompt) and we should add it soon. In the meantime, you can define it as follows:

```
[<Inline "prompt($question, $defaultResponse)">]
let Prompt (question: string) (defaultResponse: string) = null : string
```

[Edit: added types for the arguments]

Comment: For anyone else that sees this make sure you reference `IntelliFactory.Websharper.Core.Attributes`!

Comment: Opening `IntelliFactory.WebSharper` is sufficient, since the attributes such as `Inline` are aliased in an auto-opened module inside `IntelliFactory.WebSharper` (see [here](https://bitbucket.org/IntelliFactory/websharper/src/828e0890a36ec86faeea2a78b862151a29d37510/IntelliFactory.WebSharper/Pervasives.fs?at=default#cl-24)).